# Ruby: listing Fixnum methods does not include arithmetic operators

Tags: ruby

```
Fixnum.methods.sort
=> [:!, :!=, :!~, :<, :<=, :<=>, ..., :trust, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?]
```

Why doesn't it display `:*`, `:/`, `:+`, `:-`, `:%` (or `:"*"`, `":/"`, etc.) as methods?

[I see](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-2A) that they are considered methods.

Comment: `1.methods`, `Fixnum` is a class.

Comment: Try `Fixnum.instance_methods.sort`.

Comment: Metaprogramming? Hmmm

Comment: @CarySwoveland, isn't reflection a type of metaprogramming? [Some think so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641881/is-metaprogramming-a-subset-of-reflection).

Comment: `methods` and `instance_methods` are just [garden-variety](http://i.word.com/idictionary/garden-variety) Ruby methods. I don't see what that has to do with reflection. More to the point, I don't think most members searching on "Ruby" and "metaprogramming" would expect a question like yours to pop up. Consider also that yor question will be invisible to any member who filters on the "metaprogramming" tag (i.e., "no metaprogramming questions, please").

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Garden-variety or not, they still use [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) as I understand it (introspection at runtime). Practically, you're right about the SO filtering. I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: I personally think metaprogramming is a fine tag for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fixnum` is an instance of `Class`. `Class` doesn't define a `*` instance method (what would that even do), nor do `Class`'s ancestors (`Module`, `Object`, `Kernel`, `BasicObject`).

Now, `1` on the other hand is an instance of `Fixnum`, and since `Fixnum` defines a `*` instance method, that instance method shows up when you ask `1` about its methods:

```
1.methods.sort
# => [:!, :!=, :!~, :%, :&, :*, :**, :+, :+@, :-, :-@, :/, :<, :<<, :<=, … ]
```

You can see that `Fixnum` defines an instance method named `*`:

```
Fixnum.instance_methods.sort
# => [:!, :!=, :!~, :%, :&, :*, :**, :+, :+@, :-, :-@, :/, :<, :<<, :<=, … ]
```

Comment: thank you! I initially tried `Fixnum.new.methods`, but since new is not defined on fixnum, I guess I gave up on that right there.

Answer (score -1):

Because they are not class methods of `Fixnum`.