# Meta programming - Is class an object in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, metaprogramming

Instance of `package1.MyClass` is an **object** that  has identity, properties, behavior and holds  association(composition/aggregation) with other instances(objects).

Say, `package1.MySubClass` extends `package1.MyClass`

---

Below code uses `Class` meta programming abstraction,

```
Class<?> myClassInstance = Class.forName("package1.MyClass");
```

that provides information about `package1.MyClass` class.

---

1) Is `package1.MyClass` an **object**?

2) If yes, Does `package1.MyClass` **object** has it's own identity, properties, behavior and holds information about generalization relation with  `package1.MySubClass` **object**?

3) Why does Java call meta-programming as Reflection?

Comment: It's an object, not clear exactly what 2 is, and 3 is mostly because it's not metaprogramming. You want to take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic], though.

Comment: @pvg Does question 2 make sense now?

Comment: @pvg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7670562/3317808) it says, reflection is subset of metaprogramming

Comment: No. I mean, it's 3 different question, the first one and last one seem trivial and the second one is kind of incomprehensible although I kind of want to say 'yes of course it is an object with its own identity and yes of course it's not really a generalization of MySubClass, it's a parametrization of Class'

Comment: It doesn't say that. It says something along the lines of reflection being a facility useful for certain kinds of metaprogramming implementations. Java does not call 'metaprogramming' reflection because reflection doesn't mean 'metaprogramming', it means something else. Systems like C++ metaprogramming or lisp macros don't strictly depend on runtime reflection.

Comment: Anyway, I'm flagging this as 'too broad' since it's a whole bunch of stuff, doesn't seem to show any substantial independent research effort and kind of reads like someone's essay homework.

Comment: Note that syntactically, `package1.MyClass` refers to a *type*, not an object, and is a syntax error when used in a context where an object is required. On the other hand, `package1.MyClass.class` is the syntax to refer to the corresponding `Class<MyClass>` object. While they are conceptually the same thing, syntactically there is a difference.

Comment: #1) Do you mean the return value from `forName`? I mean, anything but primitives are objects in Java, so... #2)there are docs and debuggers to tell you what capabilities/properties/etc objects and classes have... #3) it doesn't, "reflection" just means you can poke around programmatically, which is a subset of meta-programming.

Comment: @DaveNewton  `x.class` is a property of `package1.MyClass` object. Isn't name `package1.MyClass` an **object** of `class` type? If primitive types(`int`/`char`) were extending `java.lang.Object` then I would *everything is an object* in Java

Comment: @overexchange And I'm saying everything that isn't a primitive (short list of primitives) in Java is an object, so if you're referring to something that isn't a primitive, it's an object. You can see exactly what it is by looking at the docs or inspecting it with a debugger.

Comment: I agree that this question is poorly researched.  It is (in part) based on false assumptions and incorrect reading of other sources;  i.e. the mistaken assertion that reflection is a kind of metaprogramming.  For the rest, those are basic questions that can easily be answered by reading *any one* of the Oracle Java tutorial, the javadocs or the JLS.  It *could be* updated to address these flaws ... but hasn't been (yet).

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) shows it *derives* from `Object`, hence it is an object.You can call `toString()`, `hashCode()` etc. on a `Class` object. In addition you can call `Class`-specific methods to identify specific properties. See the javadoc for everything available.

Note that [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) is not a Java-specific term. The term *meta-programming* isn't widely used in the Java world.

Comment: Term or capability? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7670562/3317808), it says reflection is subset of meta programming, in a language agnostic way

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd disagree that the term isn't used in Java. I'd say using the term isn't as widespread as in languages that make it easier.

Comment: I downvoted it, as an answer, it's lazy and vaguely misleading/inaccurate/incomplete. More importantly, the question itself is  poor enough to be off-topic, one's efforts are better directed at helping the poster to narrow it down and/or reformulate rather than rushing to provide a similarly poor answer.

Comment: Well I disagree (and would appreciate a comment alongside the downvote). It specifically answers points 1 and 2, and I would suggest that the phrase meta-programming is not widely used in the Java community. Most conversations I have revolve around the term (and API) reflection

Comment: You're not really owed comments on downvotes so I  find that an odd thing to complain about but ok. I think the javadoc argument seems non-fundamental and backwards. The question isn't whether  `Class` is a subtype of the type `Object`. 2 is not addressed at all and 3 is vague and kind of wrong, and again, doesn't address the question posed in 3 itself. So it's a bad answer to a bad question and does little to attempt to improve the bad question, which I think is the bigger sin. However well-intentioned, that just makes the site worse, in my mind.

Comment: 'that just makes the site worse, in my mind' - in that case editing the answer or feedback would be a valuable contribution. That's how I've seen this site grow (and helped it grow, note)